# is_number function doesn't work for me - unix shell

Tags: shell, numbers, unix

When I pass in 2009 as a arg to this shell function it returns 0, why?

```
isyear()
{
    case $arg in
        [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])   NUM=1   ;;
        *)          NUM=0   ;;
    esac
    echo $arg
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You likely mean `$1` instead of `$arg`.  `$arg` isn't defined anywhere and `$1` is the first argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use `return` instead of `echo`?

```
  return [n]
         Causes  a function to exit with the return value specified by n.
         If n is omitted, the return status is that of the  last  command
         executed  in the function body.
```

Comment: The only problem with using `return` is that it will only return values in the range 0-255. That's why `echo` is often used. In the case of this question, however, it's sufficient.

Comment: and he probably wants `return $NUM` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it should be $1 and not $arg and echo $NUM.

Answer (score 0):

Two typos:
First of all you need to use $1 not $arg to get the first parameter of the function.
Secondly I think you meant to echo $NUM rather than the passed-in argument!

```
isyear() {
      case $1 in
              [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])   NUM=1   ;;
              *)                      NUM=0   ;;
      esac
      echo $NUM 
}
```

You might also consider reworking it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

isyear() {
    case $1 in
          [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])   return 1 ;;
          *)                      return 0 ;;
    esac
}

isyear cheese
if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
  echo "Yes, it is a year!"
else
  echo "Darn!"
fi

isyear 2009
if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
  echo "Yes, it is a year!"
else
  echo "Darn!"
fi
```